# Path as a variable in attribute routing WebApi2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to use directory path as a variable (in URN) in attribute routing webApi2. Attribute route looks like the following

```
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("api/directory/{dirPath}/content")]
    public IHttpActionResult CleanDirectory(string dirPath)
    {
        //Required functionality
    }
```

So when i want to delete content in **D:\SomeDir**, i use the following url

```
    DELETE api/directory/D:\SomeDir/content
```

But this returns 404 Not found. Is it allowed to use '\' or '/' in attribute routes ?

Comment: Why don´t you provide the path as body in the request or as URL-Parameter

Comment: What happens when you URL-encode the value?  `:` and possibly `\` don't belong in a URL like that.

Comment: You also have to Urlencode the Backslash with %5c otherwise it will be converted to a normal slash / (when using a Browser) and this will break your routing.

Comment: Pass `dirPath` as a query string and make sure it is url encoded. Trying to pass it as part of the route path is only going to cause you problems.

Comment: try to add escape characters, but mainly you can get all information about routes through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: @David i used urlEncode still same issue, 404 Not Found

Comment: @Jehof & Nkosi yeah even i think i should go with query or body option